# T-SQL UPDATE using self join for a table variable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-update

Imagine there is a table:

```
declare @tab table (id int, val int)
insert into @tab(id, val)
values (1,10),(2,20),(1,15)
```

there is a need to update the table and set for every id the sum of all values with same ids in the table

```
update @tab
set val = (select sum(val) from @tab tab where tab.id = id)
```

The where clause of the last query is always true and therefore the every row would contain the sum of all values in the table.

If the table was real (not table variable) I would reference it using the table name:

```
update realtab
set val = (select sum(val) from @tab tab where tab.id = realtab.id)
```

It is possible to make such an update for table variables?

Comment: "Temporal" means "to do with time"; I think you mean "temporary", but saying "table variable" implies that anyway. I have edited.

Comment: @AakashM: sure, it is temporary variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using UPDATE ... FROM

```
update t
set val = (select sum(val) from @tab tab where tab.id = t.id)
FROM @tab t
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE  realtab
SET     val = (select sum(val) from @tab tab where tab.id = realtab.id)
FROM    @tab realtab
```

You can also use a `CTE`:

```
WITH    q AS
        (
        SELECT  *,
                SUM(val) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS sum_val
        FROM    @tab
        )
UPDATE  q
SET     val = sum_val
```